# Transform Postgres recursive query to Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, algorithm, recursion

I've got recursion, which is written in Postgresql database.

```
with recursive relations_recurs(
            pos_id, boss_pos_id, level_num, link_type, link_type_array, pos_id_array
        ) as (
            select  l.pos_id,
                    l.boss_pos_id,
                    1 as level_num,
                    l.link_type,
                    l.link_type_array,
                    l.pos_id_array
            from    temp_loop l

            union all

            select  l.pos_id,
                    l.boss_pos_id,
                    (r.level_num + 1) as level_num,
                    l.link_type,
                    (r.link_type_array || l.link_type) as link_type_array,
                    (r.pos_id_array || l.pos_id) as pos_id_array
            from    temp_pos_boss_with_min_link l
            join    relations_recurs r
            on      l.pos_id = r.boss_pos_id
            and     l.pos_id <> all (r.pos_id_array)
        )
        select  distinct pos_id_array[1] as pos_id,
                boss_pos_id as boss_pos_id,
                level_num as level_id,
                pos_id as pos_original_id,
                (case 
                    when array[1, 2] <@ t.link_type_array then 0
                    when array[1] <@ t.link_type_array then 1
                    else 2
                end) link_type
        from    relations_recurs t;
```

This is only part of whole procedure in pl/pgsql.
I want to move part of code which is recursion to another procedure LANGUAGE 'plpython3u'.
I think Python in memory can be quicker
But I'm new in python
How can I transform code from Postgres to Python.
I start it ...

```
import pandas as pd
sql_query_temp_loop = f'''
    select  l.pos_id,
                    l.boss_pos_id,
                    1 as level_num,
                    l.link_type,
                    l.link_type_array,
                    l.pos_id_array
            from    temp_loop l
    '''
sql_query_temp_pos_boss_with_min_link = f'''
    select    pos_id
            , boss_pos_id
            , min(link_type) as link_type
    from temp_pos_boss_with_min_link
    group by 1,2
    '''
temp_loop = pd.DataFrame.from_records(plpy.execute(sql_query_temp_loop))
temp_pos_boss_with_min_link = pd.DataFrame.from_records(plpy.execute(sql_query_temp_pos_boss_with_min_link))
```

Can you help to make recursion in Python?

Something wrong with my Python recursion.
I get only one last dataframe, but I can't
make it append everytime.
On every circle of recursion I see dataframe,which I
need to be merged with others

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dm_sp_land.sp_load_relations_all_py()
 LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $procedure$
from itertools import cycle, islice
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sql_query_temp_pos_boss_with_min_link = f'''
select    pos_id
            , boss_pos_id
            , link_type
from temp_pos_boss_with_min_link
'''
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(plpy.execute(sql_query_temp_pos_boss_with_min_link))
emptydf = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
emptydf = emptydf.assign(level=1)
emptydf = emptydf.assign(pos_id_array=[])
emptydf = emptydf.assign(link_type_arrays=[])
rowlevel = 0
pos_id_arrays = np.array([])
link_type_arrays = np.array([])
def getLevel(mgrid,rowlevel,pos_id_arrays,link_type_arrays, emptydf):
    if mgrid in pos_id_arrays:
        return
    else:
        rowlevel += 1
        pos_id_arrays = np.append(pos_id_arrays,  [mgrid])
        length_of_array = len(pos_id_arrays)
        length_of_array_link = len(pos_id_arrays)
        link_type_arrays = np.append(link_type_arrays,  [df[df['pos_id'] == mgrid]['link_type'].values])
        childs = df[df['boss_pos_id'] == mgrid]
        row = df[df['pos_id'] == mgrid]
        length_of_dataframe = len(row)
        pos_id_arrayska = list(map(np.copy, [pos_id_arrays] * length_of_dataframe))
        link_type_arrayska = list(map(np.copy, [link_type_arrays] * length_of_dataframe))
        row.loc[df['pos_id'] == mgrid, 'level'] = rowlevel
        row.loc[df['pos_id'] == mgrid, 'pos_id_array'] = pd.Series(pos_id_arrayska,index=row.loc[df['pos_id'] == mgrid].index)
        row.loc[df['pos_id'] == mgrid, 'link_type_arrays'] = pd.Series(link_type_arrayska,index=row.loc[df['pos_id'] == mgrid].index)
        emptydf = pd.concat([row, emptydf], ignore_index=True)
        for ind in childs.index:
            getLevel(childs['pos_id'][ind],rowlevel,pos_id_arrays,link_type_arrays,emptydf)
        return emptydf   
plpy.notice(tabulate(getLevel(99900445810,rowlevel,pos_id_arrays,link_type_arrays, emptydf), headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))       
$procedure$
;
```

Why emptydf does not merge each time?

Comment: Can you provide a MVCE with mock input data and expected output?

Comment: Examine this logic, I think you creating a graph network type association between pos(position?) and its boss.  I would look at using the networkx library.